# Batch File Executes Correctly in Console Application but not in Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, console-application, vmware

I have a simple batch file that uses the VMWare VIX API to run the VMRun.exe executable to start and stop virtual machines in VMWare Workstation 16. The executable is located in my `C:\ProgramFiles(x86)` directory.

```
@echo off
cd "C:\PROGRA~2\VMware\VMWARE~2\"
vmrun.exe -T ws Start "C:\Virtual Machines\VMTest\VMTest.vmx"
```

This batch file runs as expected both when I run it from the Command Prompt and when I call it from a C# .NET console application. The Target Framework for my Console Application is .NET Core 3.1. I execute batch file with the following code:

```
static void ExecuteCommand(string command)
        {
            int exitCode;
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
            Process process;

            processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process = Process.Start(processInfo);
            process.WaitForExit();
            exitCode = process.ExitCode;
            process.Close();
        }
```

However, I am now trying to execute it from a C# .NET Windows Service with a target framework of .NET Framework 4.7.2, and it is not able to run the command. I am using the same method as my console application, and I can run a simple batch file that creates a text file, but I can not get it to work with the VMRun.exe. I've also tried setting the service to run as my user account but that also has not worked. Both the console application and the service are configured to run as x86. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything logged in event viewer? Could be that the "start in" folder is not where you expect. Services cd into the system32 folder when they run.

Comment: The only thing I can find logged in the event viewer is the message indicating that the service started. Would the start in folder matter, since I am providing the file path for the batch file? I am able to execute it correctly when providing a simple batch script, for example: 

`echo Testing batch file writing to txt file>"C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\test.txt"`

I am able to execute this script from my service correctly. It seems that I'm having issues executing the VMRun.exe command.

Comment: I can't be sure what vmware has to do with it, if anything, but I had this exact problem yesterday with my app not being able to find appsettings.json. I had an event viewer message that was crystal clear but that could be because I hooked up a logger.